# Using jQuery UI resizable in Angular 6

Tags: angular, jquery-ui

I'm getting a `element.resizable is not a function` error when trying to use jQuery UI resizable in Angular 6.

This is my code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `<div #element 
        style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black"></div>`
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('element') theElement;

    getElement(){
         return this.theElement.nativeElement;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
           const element = this.getElement();
           element.resizable({ handles: "all" });
    }

}
```

How to get a selector from `#element` and use it in `resizable` ?

Comment: thanks, that worked

Comment: FYI it's not good practice to use jQuery in Angular applications

Comment: @TAMO That's what I heard, but I couldn't find a robust, mature, well maintained alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind jQuery to the DOM element

```
$(element).resizable({ handles: "all" });
```